# Meaning of the word "ever" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here it goes:

> Unless you are 60, you have only ever known a world of nation states.

I cannot see why the speaker used the word there. Did he use it for emphasis. If I am wrong, could you please rephrase the sentence for me?

Comment: You are right. The word is redundant - and much abused in the interests of sounding impressive, especially by the composers of romantic songs!

Comment: Who was the speaker?

Comment: The speaker is John Green from Crash Course World History

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unless you are 60, you have only ever known a world of nation states.

Or

> Unless you are 60, you have only known a world of nation states.

Both are acceptable but the inclusion of "ever" is done for emphasis.  It drives home the point that you have never known anything different.  Whether you like the emphasis or consider it superfluous is a personal choice.

Also, it really should be "Unless you are over 60..." to be an accurate statement.